# iterating through Cursor in CursorAdapter.bindView

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I'm displaying data in a `ListView` with a a custom `CursorAdapter` (posts).
some posts nay have comments (which I want to display info about) and the data is in a different cursor (I can't join the tables because I'm grouping by post id to prevent duplicates in the `ListView`).

currently in `bindView` i'm iterating through the comments `Cursor` checking if the post id equals to the current view's.

can this loop slow the UI and should be done in a different thread ? (this adds the complexity of showing the data in the correct place as the views are recycled)

is there a better strategy for doing this ? I thought about `CursorJoiner` but I don't see how I can join those two cursors.

EDIT:

this is for example in my `CurosrAdapter` implementation:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
...
...
if (mCommentsCursor != null) {
    mCommentsCursor.moveToPosition(-1);

    int count = 0;
    while (mCommentsCursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (mCommentsCursor.getInt(mCommentsCursor.getColumnIndex(
                COLUMN_COMMENT_POST_ID)) == postId) {

            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        com.setText(Integer.toString(count) + " comments");
    } else {
        com.setText(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps it'd be better if you supplied code as your post is hard to understand.

Comment: edited the question with some code

Comment: I think I get it now. Yes there absolutely must be a better strategy than this. You should set a goal of only needing one cursor in here. Right now you're running the loop for each row of the listview upon reload. If all you need is the number of comments, couldn't you just make a column in the main table for it? Then make a method to maintain this? I'd imagine it look alot like what you have

Comment: Another strategy is to run your loop (outside bindview) but put the results in a collection that will correspond to your query count and positions then you can refer to the positions of the collection in bindview with `cursor.getPosition()`

Comment: Or refer to items by having your `postid` as keys in a hashmap, if you'd prefer

Comment: the number of comments is just an example for the question, I'd also like to display the last few comments, etc..

is having an `ArrayList` of comments for each post and a `HashMap` between post id (or cursor position) and the comments collection a good strategy? doesn't sound too efficient in terms of memory usage.

Comment: i see the dilemma, i guess this comes down to taste: memory-usage vs. efficacy. If it's feasible, i'd try to make everything i need for the listview in one table. But if you're sticking to your method, you should at the very least make it so that you're going to the database at *one* id for each row, instead of looping the entire table for each row. As for what's a good strategy, i don't know how many objects that your HashMap of Arraylists and other objects might amount to and what you need everything for so i can't weigh in on that.

Comment: I prefer to have everything is one cursor as well, but its impossible in my scenario because of grouping in queries. when can I expect to face memory limit problems in Android with ArrayLists (100s, 1000s, 10000s, 100000s objects) ? objects have primitive members and Strings

Comment: well i couldn't tell you at all. Strings are objects as well and they vary in length, plus different devices have different amounts of memory. i'd guess about 220000s objects in a 64MB system, if i had to though. getting the `postid` directly and then moving your other cursor based on that for each listview row is still on the table i hope.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20476/discussion-between-gal-ben-haim-and-mango)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a `CursorJoiner` and `MatrixCursor`, more about the solution here - http://asyncindicator.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/cursorjoiner-and-matrixcursor.html